# JQuery - How to hide filter results

Tags: jquery

Below I have a `ul` list with multiple `li` elements that holds dynamic data, and it looks something like this:

```
<ul>
 <li>
  <h id='name'>some name</h>
  <h id='number'> 5 </h>
 </li>
 <li>
  <h id='name'>some name</h>
  <h id='number'> 1 </h>
 </li>
</ul>
```

I want to hide an entire `li` block when the number is greater than or equal to 2. The code below only hides the actual number heading instead of the whole `li` block. I tried prepending `.parent()` before the `.hide()` and that didn't do anything. Any help would be appreciated!

```
$("li #number").filter(getNum).hide();

 function getNum(){
    var num = (parseInt($(this).text())); 
      if (num >= 2) {
        return num //returns numbers I want to hide
      }
 }
```

Comment: Using multiple elements with same `ID`'s isn't good practice.

Comment: Along with that this won't work correctly with that selector, because `id`'s are supposed to be unique. The selector `"li #number"` will only get the single `<h id='number'> 5 </h>`. You should use a `class`. Also you never closed your first `<li>`, along with the second and the `<ul>`.

Comment: The list is generated dynamically. Is there a solution around this?

Comment: @david Are you saying the data is dynamic and you use that to generate the HTML, or the HTML itself cannot be changed? If you are saying the HTML cannot be changed then no because your HTML is not valid.

Comment: I didn't write out the exact HTML code; I just wrote the basic structure. And yes, the data is dynamic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, your `html` document is not valid, since the IDs must be unique, if you have more than one element the best option is to use the classes. in addition to this, using the parent will hide the complete li element.

```js
$("li .number").filter(getNum).parent('li').hide();
 function getNum(){
   var num = (parseInt($(this).text())); 
     if (num >= 2) {
       return num //returns numbers I want to hide
   }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
 <li>
  <h class='name'>some name</h>
  <h class='number'> 5 </h>
 </li>
 <li>
  <h class='name'>some name</h>
  <h class='number'> 1 </h>
 </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `class` instead of duplicate `id` and use `parent` to hide entire `li`.

```js
$("li .number").filter(getNum).parent('li').hide();

 function getNum(){
    var num = (parseInt($(this).text())); 
      if (num >= 2) {
        return num //returns numbers I want to hide
      }
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <h class='name'>some name</h>
    <h class='number'> 5 </h>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h class='name'>some name</h>
    <h class='number'> 1 </h>
  </li>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try :

```
$("li").show().filter(function getNum() {
    return parseInt($(this).find('.number').text()) >= 2;
}).hide();
```

`.show()` is necessary if the filter will be applied more than once, otherwise filtered out items may stay hidden despite their value having increased to be >= 2. If the filter is applied only once, `.show()` will do no harm.

You probably want a better initial selector. `$("li")` will select all `<li>` elements on the page. Something of the general form `$("ul#myList li")` would be more specific.

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Use `parent()` to hide `li` and use class because `id` is unique element.

```js
$("li .number").filter(getNum).parent().hide();

 function getNum(){
    var num = (parseInt($(this).text())); 
      if (num >= 2) {
        return num //returns numbers I want to hide
      }
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
 <li>
  <h class='name'>some name</h>
  <h class='number'> 5 </h>
 <li>
  <h class='name'>some name</h>
  <h class='number'> 1 </h>
</ul>
```